# How to programatically retrieve (through API) Performance & Diagnostic data for Azure Virtual Machines?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have created a new Virtual Machine in my Azure Subscription. When I check its properties, I can find the diagnostic & performance data in 'Monitor' tab in Azure Management Portal.

My question is: Are there any APIs to retrieve this data programatically in an application?